# From a NextJS pod, how do I call an API that's located in a different pod but in the same Kubernetes dev cluster and namespace?

Tags: rest, kubernetes, next.js, environment-variables, next.js13

I have a NextJS app that I added to our namespace's dev cluster such that when I call `Kubectl get all --namespace [my-namespace]` I get back:

```
NAME                                       READY   STATUS     RESTARTS  AGE
pod/[my-namespace]-[my-nextjs-app]-[podId]  1/1     Running    0         3d
```

I am trying to call an API that is located in another (backend) app but in the same namespace. With the aforementioned command, I also get:

```
NAME                TYPE      CLUSTER-IP        EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)   AGE
service/second-app  ClusterIP 172...{restOfIP}   <none>      8083/TCP  304d
```

I then run the command:
`kubectl port-forward my-nextjs-app-<podID> 3000:3000 -n [my-namespace]`
And I'm able to access my app on port 3000 and navigate the UI, but when I call the APIs, I don't get any data back. I get "Network Error", "Axios Error"...

The URL I am calling from my nextjs app is `"http://second-app:8083/{restOfApiUrl...}"`.

I don't understand why I am getting these errors? I have environmental variables configured as such:

```
#{myNextJsRepo}/k8s/environments/development/configmap.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: my-nextjs-app
data:
    second-app-host: second-app
    second-app-port: '8083'
```

and

```
#{myNextJsRepo}/k8s/application/deployment.yaml

containers:
                - image: my-nextjs-app:latest
                  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
                  name: my-nextjs-app
                  env:
                      - name: NEXT_PUBLIC_SECOND_APP_HOST
                        valueFrom:
                            configMapKeyRef:
                                name: my-nextjs-app
                                key: second-app-host
                      - name: NEXT_PUBLIC_SECOND_APP_PORT
                        valueFrom:
                            configMapKeyRef:
                                name: my-nextjs-app
                                key: second-app-port
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 3000
```

and

```
#{myNextJsRepo}/next.config.js

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

module.exports = {
    env: {
        NEXT_PUBLIC_SECOND_APP_HOST: 'second-app',
        NEXT_PUBLIC_SECOND_APP_PORT: '8083',
    },
};
```

What I've tried:

I have tried to update the env variables with `next.config.js` as shown previously, and also update the `env` variables in the `deployment.yaml`, `configmap.yaml`, and `next.config.js` with the actual `clusterIP` of my second-app's `service`. Yet calling

```
http://172{...restOfSecondAppIP}:8083/{restOfApiUrl...}
```

did not work either. I also tried *only* using the Kubernetes `env` variables, such that there were no `env` variables in `next.config.js`, but with that the API I was calling resulted in `http://undefined:undefined/{restOfApiUrl...}`

I also tried `port-forwarding` my second app at the same time in a different terminal, but that didn't solve the issue either. The ONLY time I actually was able to get data back in the next-js-app in the dev cluster, was when I port-forwarded my second app using the command:

```
kubectl port-forward second-app-<podID>  8083:8083 -n my-namespace
```

**AND**

updated the env variables from 'second-app' or 'my-second-app-cluster-ip' to 'localhost', such that the url that was called was `http://localhost:8083/{restOfApiUrl...}`. However, I was told that this was not the right approach because the data was essentially being accessed from my laptop, but not from the Kubernetes dev cluster.

I am expecting to be able to call the API from one pod to the other inside a Kubernetes dev cluster and get the data back. Your help is much appreciated!

**Edit**: Upon request, I've added my `service.yaml` here:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nextjs-app
  labels:
    app: my-nextjs-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    name: http
  selector:
    app: my-nextjs-app
```

Comment: do you make request from browser or from the server?

Comment: can you share your service definition YAML and the endpoint resources from the namespace

Comment: Hi @Yilmaz, I am making the request from the browser. In terminal I do:

wget -O - 'http://second-app:8083/{restOfUrl}' --header='Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' --header='Referer: http://localhost:3000/' --header='User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' | cat

And I get back:
Connecting to second-app:8083 (172.{...restOfIp}
writing to stdout
- 100% |****
{
"code": 200, 
"message": "Second App is healthy", 
...,
}

In the browser, calling the same url, I get "Network Error"

Comment: Sure @PEkambaram. 
Edit: For better formatting, I've added it in the question description

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nextjs-app
  labels:
    app: my-nextjs-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    name: http
  selector:
    app: my-nextjs-app

Comment: did you configure your dns. also mention your os. kubctl environment differs in each os. network error means you cannot even reached to a network to make a request. if you could not reach service pod, you would get econnrefused error

Comment: Hey @Yilmaz. Thanks for your reply! 'Configure my dns'? Do you mean replacing 'second-app' with 'second-app.default' or 'second-app.myNamespace' in the 'configmap.yaml'?

OS is MacOS M Chip

Comment: @Yilmaz because if so, I tried that (second-app.myNamespace) but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use port-forwarding to access a pod directly. Some applications cannot connect to a host by using a name like the service name. For these types of applications, you must use the IP address and port of your second service.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your reply @Ahmad-pirouze. I've tried using originally the exact IP address, but that did not return data in the browser. Only in the terminal.

Comment: Have you tried replacing your second-app service cluster-ip in second-app-host?
If yes, that means you can connect directly to your service. If not, your second service has a problem, not your connection.

Comment: I had tried to use only the IP of the service. That unfortunately didn't work. The url ended up being 'http://undefined:undefined/{restOfApiUrl...}'. I will try however, updating the configmap.yaml with 'second-app.myNamespace' instead of just the current 'second-app'. Not sure if that will fix, will update!

Answer (score 0):

When running apps in Kubernetes, you should always configure a *Service* that points to the port of that service. This allows you to connect to the pods your apps from the Kubernetes cluster and configure access from outside the cluster.
For example, if I have this service for my app:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
```

When this service is located in the namespace `my-namespace`, you can connect to your app with the domain `my-service.my-namespace.cluster.local` or `my-service.my-namespace` depending on you network provider.
So to connect to your backend app from your nextjs frontend app, you should use `second-app.my-namespace`. If this doesn't work try `second-app.my-namespace.cluster.local`.

I copied the example service from https://www.educative.io/blog/kubernetes-deployments-pods-services, it explains the concepts of a Kubernetes deployment quite good.
I you want more information on services, have a look at the [Kubernetes Service documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/), especially the section about [dns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#dns).
For an interactive tutorial to deploy an app to Kubernetes, have a look at the Kubernetes tutorial [Lean Kubernetes Basics](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/)

Comment: Hmm thanks for your reply. I tried 'second-app.my-namespace' in the configmap and in next.config.js, but has not solved issue. I have yet to try 'second-app.my-namespace.cluster.local' but, both apps are in the same namespace, it should resolve the dns automatically...

Comment: It was the same for me. 'second-app.my-namespace' didn't work, but 'second-app.my-namespace.cluster.local' worked

Comment: trying it @8bit

Answer (score 0):

you are in the same namespace. two pods communicate each other with clusterIp service.

```
kubectl get namespace
```

get the service of your namespace

```
kubectl get services -n your-name-space-here
```

You have the service name now. if you are on the server, you are going to make request  to this

```
 http://yourServiceName.yourNameSpaceName.svc.cluster.local
```

you have to add the route for the pod

```
 http://yourServiceName.yourNameSpaceName.svc.cluster.local/api/yourRoute
```

this should work because you did not specify `host` in service.yaml. if you had a host, you would add header option

```
    avait axios.get(" http://yourServiceName.yourNameSpaceName.svc.cluster.local",{
   headers:{
      Host:"yourSpecifiedHostinService"
}
})
```